# Is it possible to aggregate data with varying nesting depth in Grafana?

Tags: graphite, grafana

I have data in Grafana with different nesting depths. It looks like this (the nesting depth differs depending on the message type):

```
foo.<host>.type.<type-id>
foo.<host>.type.<type-id>.<subtype-id>
foo.<host>.type.<type-id>.<subtype-id>.<more-nesting>
...
```

The `<host>` field can be the IP of the server sending the data and `<type-id>` is the type of message that it handled. There are quite a lot of message types but for the visualization I am only interested in the first level of `<type-id>` aggregated over all hosts.

For example, if I have this data:

```
foo.ip1.type.type1 = 3
foo.ip1.type.type2.subtype1 = 5
foo.ip2.type.type1 = 4
foo.ip2.type.type2.subtype1 = 9
foo.ip2.type.type2.subtype2 = 13
```

I would rather see it like this:

```
foo.*.type.type1 = 7 (3+4)
foo.*.type.type2 = 27 (5+9+13)
```

Then it would be easier to produce a graph where you can see which types of messages are most frequent.

I have not found a way to express that in Grafana. The only option that I see is to create a graph by manually creating queries for each message type. If there were only a handful of types that would be OK, but in my example, the number of types is quite high and even worse, they can change over time. When new message types are added, I would like to see them without having to change the graph.

Does Grafana support to aggregate the data in such a way? Can it visualize the data aggregated by one node and while summing up everything that comes after the node (like the `--max-depth` option in the Unix `du` command)?

---

I am not very experienced with Grafana, but I am starting to believe this functionality is not supported. Not sure whether Grafana allows to preprocess the data, but if the data could be transformed to

```
foo.ip1.type.type1 = 3
foo.ip1.type.type2_subtype1 = 5
foo.ip2.type.type1 = 4
foo.ip2.type.type2_subtype1 = 9
foo.ip2.type.type2_subtype2 = 13
```

it would also be valid workaround as the number of subtypes in very low in my data (often there is even only one subtype).

Answer (score 0):

I think the groupByNode function might be useful to you. By doing something like:

```
groupByNode(foo.ip1.type.*.*,3,"sumSeries")
```

You'll need to repeat this for each level of nesting. Hope that helps.

More information is available here:
http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.groupByNode

If you want to do it the way you alluded to in your example you could use aliasSub